# Custom Inclusive TakeWhile(), is there a better way?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I've written a custom LINQ extension method that extends the `TakeWhile()` method to be inclusive, rather than exclusive when the predicate is false.

```
        public static IEnumerable<T> TakeWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, bool inclusive)
        {
            source.ThrowIfNull("source");
            predicate.ThrowIfNull("predicate");

            if (!inclusive)
                return source.TakeWhile(predicate);

            var totalCount = source.Count();
            var count = source.TakeWhile(predicate).Count();

            if (count == totalCount)
                return source;
            else
                return source.Take(count + 1);
        }
```

While this works, I'm sure there is a better way of doing it. I'm fairly sure that this doesn't work in terms of deferred execution/loading.

`ThrowIfNull()` is a extension method for `ArgumentNullException` checking

Can the community provide some some hints or re-writes? :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are correct; this is not friendly to deferred execution (calling `Count` requires a full enumeration of the source).

You could, however, do this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> TakeWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, bool inclusive)
{
    foreach(T item in source)
    {
        if(predicate(item)) 
        {
            yield return item;
        }
        else
        {
            if(inclusive) yield return item;

            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! A much nicer solution that mine :)

Comment: This is fantastic. Especially when you need a TakeWhile with inverted logic, i.e. take everything while predicate is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

Essentially the same answer as @adamrobinson but just a different signature that seems to align with built-in extensions in case anyone searches for a `TakeUntil`.

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeUntil<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate )
    {
        foreach ( var item in source )
        {
            yield return item;

            if ( predicate( item ) )
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Тot a direct answer to the question. I want to show how you can use `SkipWhile` to simulate inclusive `TakeWhile` logic.

```
IEnumerable<string> list = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5" };
var result = list
    .Reverse()
    .SkipWhile(item => item != "3")
    .Reverse();
// result will be {"1", "2", "3"}
```

However note that doing it this way will be less efficient, because essentially, `list` in this case has to to be reversed twice. So make sure performance will not be an issue.