# TakeWhile, but get the element that stopped it also

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-objects

I'd like to use the LINQ `TakeWhile` function on LINQ to Objects. However, I also need to know the first element that "broke" the function, i.e. the first element where the condition was not true.

Is there a single function to get all of the objects that don't match, plus the first that does?

For example, given the set `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}`,

```
mySet.MagicTakeWhile(x => x != 5);
```

`=> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: You can write a method like that easily, but this won't be "lazy" since you must know the position of the last item in order to get the next one.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2242318/241211) is not quite a duplicate, but shares [an answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6817553/241211)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can use [SkipWhile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549075.aspx), and then take the first element.

```
var elementThatBrokeIt = data.SkipWhile(x => x.SomeThing).Take(1);
```

UPDATE

If you want a single extension method, you can use the following:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MagicTakeWhile<T>(this IEnumerable<T> data, Func<T, bool> predicate) {
    foreach (var item in data) {
        yield return item;
        if (!predicate(item))
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would require multiple calls. I could just do `FirstOrDefault` in that case.

Comment: @Maarten, good answer - you can save a line by removing the final `yield break;`

Comment: The original answer one-liner can't work. That is not how it works. .Take(n) takes a collection and returns the same collection, but caps it after n element(s). In this case. It will take the collection returned from SkipWhile and then take 1 element from it. Effectively a FirstOrDefault. It will NOT "append" the collection.

Comment: This didn't work for me when the element was the first in the list - I get the first two elements.  Ended up using this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098714/1579626

Answer (score 7):

LINQ to Objects doesn't have such an operator. But it's straightforward to implement a `TakeUntil`  extension yourself. Here's [one such implementation](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs) from [moreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/).

Comment: Unfortunately they don't include this in the MoreLinq NuGet. I'll copy & paste the code. Thanks!

Comment: The name ``TakeUntil`` doesn't convey the meaning. ``Take`` eggs from the box ``Until`` you get a bad one doesn't mean you take the bad one.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing TakeUntilInclusive?

Comment: TakeUntil is now included in MoreLinq NuGet.  Also here's an updated link from GitHub: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/TakeUntil.cs

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
var a = new[] 
    {
        "two",
        "three",
        "four",
        "five",
    };
  Func<string, bool> predicate = item => item.StartsWith("t");      
  a.TakeWhile(predicate).Concat(new[] { a.SkipWhile(predicate).FirstOrDefault() })
```

Comment: This also takes two function calls. Also, you could skip the `SkipWhile` and go right to `a.FirstOrDefault(predicate)`.

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't work if the source enumerable changes with each enumeration, i.e. a stream of numbers from a RNG.