# Extract part of string where searchkeyword is found using regex

Tags: regex

The string looks like

Maximum number of Utilisations

```
A Borrower (or the Parent) may not deliver a Utilisation Request if as a result of the proposed Utilisation:<br/>
[10] or more Term Loans [(other than Incremental Company Loans)] would be outstanding; [or]<br/>
[15] or more Revolving Company Utilisations would be outstanding[; or<br/>
[20] or more Incremental Company Loans would be outstanding].<br/>
A Borrower (or the Parent) may not request that a Company A Loan [or an Incremental Company Loan] be divided if, as a result of the proposed division, [  25      ] or more Company A Loans [or [  50    ] or more Incremental Company Loans] would be outstanding.<br/>
[A Borrower (or the Parent) may not request that a Company B Loan or a Company C Loan be divided.]
```

Expected outputs:

```
[ 10 ] or more Term Loans [(other than Incremental Company Loans)] would be outstanding; 
[ 15 ] or more Revolving Company Utilisations would be outstanding[; or
[ 20 ] or more Incremental Company Loans would be outstanding].
```

What i was trying which doesn't seem to be working

```
Regex = '.*other than Incremental Company Loans.*'
```

This returns whole paragraph. There could be other way to do this, but we have to do this using REGEX only.

Comment: Are your "lines" separated with `<br/>`? Is that HTML? The easiest is to replace all `<br/>` with `\n`, and use a non-regex solution I already shared with you.

Comment: correct... thats how we are getting the string back from database...

Comment: So, why regex? `inputText.Split(new[] {"<br/>"}, StringSplitOptions.None).Where(x => x.Contains("other than Incremental Facility Loans"))`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Thanks, but is it doable using REGEX?

Comment: Yes, but why? Could you please explain where you are using it? The performance/readability with regex will be poorer than with pure code.

Comment: BTW, your expected matches do not contain `other than Incremental Facility Loans`. Could you please check your data/expected results?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - made the changes to output string... i mentioned it correctly. I wasnt aware performance issue with regex... can you help in inputText.Split  approach for 3 output results expected. Please put this in answer so that i can accept it quickly

Comment: After your edit, I see that you want to get the "lines" from the match up to the full stop. Right? I am not sure I understand the rule for extraction here. The sample string and expected result are not clarifying everything here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Tried to do more formatting, not sure if that would help. But yes you are right get the "lines" from the match up to the full stop...or semicolon

Comment: Since you are writing in C#, see [a C# demo](https://ideone.com/ivo6Qg), no regex involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pure regex approach may not suffice since you might want to further replace `<br/>` with line breaks, and the pattern is rather complex:

```
(?<=^|<br/>)(?:(?!<br/>).)*other than Incremental Company Loans[\s\S]*?(?=[.;]<br/>|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/unH0DY/3)

It matches:

- `(?<=^|<br/>)` - a location preceded with start of string or `<br/>` substring
- `(?:(?!<br/>).)*` - any char, 0+ occurrences, that does not start `<br/>` substring
- `other than Incremental Company Loans` - search string
- `[\s\S]*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
- `(?=[.;]<br/>|$)` - immediately followed with `.` or `;` followed with `<br/>` or end of string.

As you are writing the code in C#, you may use a [non-regex solution](https://ideone.com/ivo6Qg) that is very readable and easier to adjust:

```
var s = "A Borrower (or the Parent) may not deliver a Utilisation Request if as a result of the proposed Utilisation:<br/>[10] or more Term Loans [(other than Incremental Company Loans)] would be outstanding; [or]<br/>[15] or more Revolving Company Utilisations would be outstanding[; or<br/>[20] or more Incremental Company Loans would be outstanding].<br/>A Borrower (or the Parent) may not request that a Company A Loan [or an Incremental Company Loan] be divided if, as a result of the proposed division, [  25      ] or more Company A Loans [or [  50    ] or more Incremental Company Loans] would be outstanding.<br/>[A Borrower (or the Parent) may not request that a Company B Loan or a Company C Loan be divided.]";
var result = s.Split(new[] {"<br/>"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .SkipWhile(x => !x.Contains("other than Incremental Company Loans"))
    .MagicTakeWhile(x => !x.EndsWith(".") && !x.EndsWith(";"));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", result));
```

Output:

```
[10] or more Term Loans [(other than Incremental Company Loans)] would be outstanding; [or]
[15] or more Revolving Company Utilisations would be outstanding[; or
[20] or more Incremental Company Loans would be outstanding].
```

The `MagicTakeWhile` method is borrowed from [TakeWhile, but get the element that stopped it also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11883524/3832970). It takes items until a condition is met *including* the last item where the condition stops being met.

Comment: How can i add MagicTakeWhile to asp.net web page... bcos this is a class method

Comment: You should put it into a public static class.

Comment: @user3657339 Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.